# Property testable in sublinear time in bounded degree graphs but not in general graphs

Tags: reference-request, randomized-algorithms, property-testing

Is there some natural property that is testable in strongly sublinear time (i.e. $O(n^{1-\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon > 0$) in bounded-degree graphs but not in general graphs? If not such property is known, is there some good candidate? For example, is there a property testable in strongly sublinear time in bounded-degree graphs, for which no such algorithm is known for general graphs (as opposed to one where we know this is actually not possible)?

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 10.5.1 of Oded Goldreich's *Introduction to Property Testing* (2017) discusses exactly that question. (See [his website](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/pt-intro.html) for an overview of the book, and (free) access to the drafts.)

Now, Theorem 10.15 states there are properties, for instance *cycle-freeness*, *subgraph-freeness*, and *degree regularity*, which have $O_\varepsilon(1)$-query testers in the bounded-degree model, but require $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ queries in the general graph model. This holds even under strong promises on both the average and maximum degree of the graph.

There also is a qualitatively similar gap (but quantitatively weaker) for triangle freeness, as discussed after Theorem 10.15.

---

You may argue that even though there is a clear separation (constant vs. polynomial), this is still strongly sublinear. However, I am a little unclear on whether your notion of sublinear is the right one in this model anyways, where the size of the input is $n+|E|$ (which ranges between $n$ and $n^2$).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am aware of that chapter, but I was asking more specifically about linear/superlinear. But I agree with your second point. I guess a more relevant question is $m^{1-c}$ instead of $n^{1-c}$.